# Удалить лишние пробелы без регулярок JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить лишние пробелы в строке без использования регулярных выражений.

Например:

```
// input
____ = пробел
let str = 'smth________good'

//output
smth good
```

Comment: А как Вы это себе представляете? Вы можете явно через replace() задать строку на замену, но если Вам надо более сложные условия (по типу неопределенного количества нижних подчеркиваний) – это уже регулярки

Comment: @VladimirGonchar строку можно представить как массив. `str.split(" ").filter(e=>e).join(" ")` :).

Comment: @xydope Благодарю!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let str = 'smth          good           zxc      someone'

function strip(str){
    let arr = str.split(' ')
    return arr.filter(item => item).join(' ') 
}

console.log(strip(str))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]